# var function calling for unknown reason

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I have the code below, and it seems to call the `var promiseFeedback` is called and I don't know why... This means it is called even when an error occurs when I create document. Whereas is should only be called if there is no `err` in the createDocument.

Is anyone able to clear up why?

```
if (json) {
    createDocument(documentUrl, context, json, function(res){
    var promiseFeedback = callFB (context, res);
    var collection = `mydb`

    client.createDocument(collection, res, (err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            context.log(err);
            return context.done();
        } else {
            Promise.all([promiseFeedback]).then(function(results){ 
            context.log("promiseFeedback: " + results[0]);
            context.done();
            });
        }
    });
    });
}
function callFB(context, res) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        var requestUrl = url.parse( URL );
            var requestBody = {
                "id": res.id
            };

            var body = JSON.stringify( requestBody );

            const requestOptions = {
                hostname: requestUrl.hostname,
                path: requestUrl.path,
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body),
                }
            };

            var request = https.request(requestOptions, function(res) {
                var data ="";
                res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                    data += chunk
                });
                res.on('end', function () {
                resolve(true);
                })
            }).on('error', function(error) {
                context.log("request error:", error);
                resolve(false);
            });
            request.write(body);
            request.end();
            });    
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `callFB`?

Comment: Added `callFB` - I am unsure why it calls twice. I assumed that setting the function as a `var` wouldn't trigger it

Comment: Can you please explain it in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var promiseFeedback = callFB (context, res);
```

This statement executes `callFB` immediately, not just assigns another name to the promise. This promise `callFB` is out of the callback(scope) of `err` and `Promise.all([promiseFeedback])`, it runs no matter what the result of `client.createDocument` is.

To fix this:

Remove `var promiseFeedback = callFB (context, res);` and change  `Promise.all([promiseFeedback])` to `callFB(context, res)`.  You don't need to use  `Promise.all` as you only have one promise to resolve.

Or you can just move `var promiseFeedback = callFB (context, res);` into else segment.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I realise I don't need the promise there for one function, however I was just testing before adding a second. To solve this would I have to add `var promiseFeedback = callFB (context, res);` inside the `else` of `client.createDocument`?
Also, what do you mean by your last paragraph? What would I be looking into the bindings to find out? Thanks again

Comment: @JDT Sorry for the late, you're right, putting that statement in else segment could also do the trick. About the cosmosdb output binding, it's an on-premise feature provided by Azure function, which can configure cosmosdb connection string, database and collection name in function.json and other configurations in app settings, which reduces the common connection and create logic in code. You can ignore this tip as I don't find a way to make the binding statement work with callback(or sth similar).